# Functional compositon is slower than multiple iterations

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, functional-programming

I was doing a basic example of understanding functional composition over using maps and was quite puzzled by performance results

```
const doubleIt = (x) => x*2
const render = (x) => `<li>${x}</li>`
const composeRenderAndDouble = function (x) {
    return render(doubleIt(x));
}
const arr = Array(1000).fill(0)

const mergeArraysAndFunctionalManyMaps = (arr) => arr.map(doubleIt).map(render)
const mergeArraysAndFunctionalOneMap = (arr) => arr.map(composeRenderAndDouble)


mergeArraysAndFunctionalManyMaps(arr)// executes in 0.788ms
mergeArraysAndFunctionalOneMap(arr)// executes in 1.184ms
```

I have tried running the code several times and every single time multiple maps is faster than one map with functional composition inside.

Running in the Node environment(v10)
I would presume that multiple maps will be slower as we are performing multiple iterations over the same array?

Comment: Maybe there are some optimisation behind the multiple map and only one iteration is performed

Comment: That's the thing i'm trying to understand. seems quite magical to me

Comment: Honestly, micro optimization such as this is a waste of time.

Comment: Change the iteration count to `1e6` and see what happens...

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. For me (in node 10 and chrome 67)  `ManyMaps` is roughly 20% slower than `OneMap`.

Comment: Tried with 1e6

​​​​​677.157ms​​​​​ at ​​​mergeArraysAndFunctionalManyMaps(arr)​​​ ​quokka.js:12:0​

​​​​​467.531ms​​​​​ at ​​​mergeArraysAndFunctionalOneMap(arr)​​​ ​quokka.js:13:0​

Comment: Which confirms your presumption, right? And most importantly, this proves that for most cases you can pick one over the other based on clarity/readability/maintainability, rather than performance optimizations.

Comment: @mfilimonov Apparently the allocation of a thousand-element-array is negligible, but the allocation of a million-element-array is not.

Comment: I do wonder why no one added an answer ? comments are the new answers on SF?

Comment: @mfilimonov because the question is unanswerable. There is sufficient difference between JS implementations (and indeed the 'same' implementation over time) that what is faster on one may be slower on another. JITs get smarter, usage patterns (and they do pay attention to those) change. Nor is the difference significant: slightly less than half a second vs slightly more than half a second for a million element array? There's a ~100ms swing which is *maybe* barely enough for a perceptible UX diff.